# PHP mysql update and insert if condition is satisfying

Tags: php, mysql

With the below code i am trying to update a table using the post values. After updating, with the same variables i am trying to insert the values to another table with if condition. The first update is working properly, but the insert is not happening.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $wlnid=$_POST['wlt_ln_id'];
    $refwal = $_POST['wlt_name'];
    $refamt = $_POST['wlt_ln_refund_amt'];
    $refdtls = $_POST['wlt_ln_txn_details'];
    $refdate = $_POST['wlt_ln_refund_date'];
    $lntype = $_POST['wlt_ln_type'];

      $query=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "update wallet_loans set wlt_ln_refund_acct = '$refwal',wlt_ln_refund_amt=wlt_ln_refund_amt+'$refamt',wlt_ln_refund_txn_details='$refdtls',wlt_ln_refund_date='$refdate' where wlt_ln_id = '$wlnid'and wlt_holder_id = '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}'");

      if($lntype == 'Given'){
          $sql = "INSERT INTO wallet_txns(wlt_name, wlt_txn_date, wlt_txn_type, wlt_drcr_cod, wlt_txn_amount, wlt_txn_dtls, wlt_txn_cat, wlt_txn_cat_sub, wlt_amt_payee, wlt_holder_id, wlt_txn_flg_loan, wlt_txn_ln_id, wlt_txn_flg_recr, wlt_txn_recr_id) VALUES ( '$refwal', '$refdate', 'Income','C', '$refamt', '$refdtls', 'Loan refund','Null','Null', '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}', 'Y','$wlnid', 'N',0)";
      }

      else if($lntype == 'Received'){
          $sql = "INSERT INTO wallet_txns(wlt_name, wlt_txn_date, wlt_txn_type, wlt_drcr_cod, wlt_txn_amount, wlt_txn_dtls, wlt_txn_cat, wlt_txn_cat_sub, wlt_amt_payee, wlt_holder_id, wlt_txn_flg_loan, wlt_txn_ln_id, wlt_txn_flg_recr, wlt_txn_recr_id) VALUES ( '$refwal', '$refdate', 'Expense','D', '$refamt', '$refdtls', 'Loan refund','Null','Null', '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}', 'Y','$wlnid', 'N',0)";
      }
}?>
```

Advance thanks for all supports.

Comment: What is in $lntype? And I don't see you executing the SQL query after the if's.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: $lntype is a  text select field in my html page, with value (Given and Received). based on the Given or Received i am inserting to another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are never calling `mysqli_query` with your sql query.

```
if ($lntype == 'Given') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO wallet_txns(wlt_name, wlt_txn_date, wlt_txn_type, wlt_drcr_cod, wlt_txn_amount, wlt_txn_dtls, wlt_txn_cat, wlt_txn_cat_sub, wlt_amt_payee, wlt_holder_id, wlt_txn_flg_loan, wlt_txn_ln_id, wlt_txn_flg_recr, wlt_txn_recr_id) VALUES ( '$refwal', '$refdate', 'Income','C', '$refamt', '$refdtls', 'Loan refund','Null','Null', '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}', 'Y','$wlnid', 'N',0)";
        mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql);
}
else if($lntype == 'Received'){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO wallet_txns(wlt_name, wlt_txn_date, wlt_txn_type, wlt_drcr_cod, wlt_txn_amount, wlt_txn_dtls, wlt_txn_cat, wlt_txn_cat_sub, wlt_amt_payee, wlt_holder_id, wlt_txn_flg_loan, wlt_txn_ln_id, wlt_txn_flg_recr, wlt_txn_recr_id) VALUES ( '$refwal', '$refdate', 'Expense','D', '$refamt', '$refdtls', 'Loan refund','Null','Null', '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}', 'Y','$wlnid', 'N',0)";
    mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql);
}
```

Comment: ` mysqli_query($sql);` is not correct. first argument is database connection object. check your code.thanks.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Thanks for the tip... I forgot about it.... Its working now... the updated code. '$sql = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO wallet_txns(wlt_name, wlt_txn_date, wlt_txn_type, wlt_drcr_cod, wlt_txn_amount, wlt_txn_dtls, wlt_txn_cat, wlt_txn_cat_sub, wlt_amt_payee, wlt_holder_id, wlt_txn_flg_loan, wlt_txn_ln_id, wlt_txn_flg_recr, wlt_txn_recr_id) VALUES ( '$refwal', '$refdate', 'Income','C', '$refamt', '$refdtls', 'Loan refund','Null','Null', '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}', 'Y','$wlnid', 'N',0)");'

Comment: Thank you @anantkumarsingh. I've updated the code. I tried looking in the [docs](http://php.net/mysqli_query) and looked at the wrong method.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Sure, done. thanks for the tip and support.